# Random divs, display only part of them

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I use this code on my website to randomize the order of divs. On one of my subpages I want to use it in slightly modified version - there will be 12 divs displayed in random order again but only the first 3 will be displayed, the rest will be set to "display:none;" or similiar effect using js.

Any suggestions how to modify the following code, so that only 3 first divs will appear?

Here is the code: http://jsfiddle.net/ca7WW/

HTML:

```
<div class="randomize">
    <div class="random_div">1</div>
    <div class="random_div">2</div>
    <div class="random_div">3</div>
    <div class="random_div">4</div>
    <div class="random_div">5</div>
    <div class="random_div">6</div>
    <div class="random_div">7</div>
    <div class="random_div">8</div>
    <div class="random_div">9</div>
    <div class="random_div">10</div>
    <div class="random_div">11</div>
    <div class="random_div">12</div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
function shuffle(array) {
  var currentIndex = array.length
    , temporaryValue
    , randomIndex
    ;

  // While there remain elements to shuffle...
  while (0 !== currentIndex) {

    // Pick a remaining element...
    randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
    currentIndex -= 1;

    // And swap it with the current element.
    temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
    array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
    array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
  }

  return array;
}

(function ($) {
    $.fn.randomize = function (childElem) {
        return this.each(function () {
            var $this = $(this);
            var elems = shuffle($(childElem));
            $this.remove(childElem);
            for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++)
            $this.append(elems[i]);
        });
    }
})(jQuery)

jQuery(function($){
    $("div.randomize").randomize("div.random_div");
});
```

Comment: Just a sidenote... I'd suggest using [detach](https://api.jquery.com/detach/) instead of remove so that the div elements keep all their associated jquery data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `:lt` and `:gt` to get the "first N" or the "last N" elements in your selector.

[***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/4HkDL/)

```
jQuery(function($){
    $("div.randomize").randomize("div.random_div");
    $(".random_div:gt(2)").hide(); // This hides anything after the 3rd element
});
```

Comment: Wow, just one line and works like a charm! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

First use an ID for the container, so you can call it easily:

```
<div id="randomize">
    <div class="random_div">1</div>
    <div class="random_div">2</div>
    <div class="random_div">3</div>
    <div class="random_div">4</div>
    ...
</div>
```

then add this javascript:

```
var divs = document.getElementById('randomize').getElementsByTagName('div');
var nr = 1;
for(var a = 0 ; a < divs.length ; a++){
    if(divs[a].getAttribute('class') == 'random_div'){
        if(nr <= 3){
            divs[a].style.display = 'inherit';
        }else{
            divs[a].style.display = 'block';
        }
        nr = nr + 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: @kei Your solution looks better and faster

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will go with kei's solution tho.

Comment: I figured ;). Seems way faster!

Answer (score 1):

Try this: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bradleytrager/42jgm/)

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.randomize = function (childElem) {
        return this.each(function () {
            var $this = $(this);
            var elems = shuffle($(childElem));
            $this.remove(childElem);
            for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++){
                $this.append(elems[i]);

                //Show only the first three elements
                if (i <= 2){
                   $(elems[i]).show();
                }else{
                    $(elems[i]).hide();
               }
            }
        });
    }
})(jQuery)
```

Edit:  I agree that @kei has a cleaner and more flexible answer.  I would just like to point out that his solution should only be used if you are randomizing the div's one time on the page load.  If you would like to randomize them multiple times make sure to un-hide the divs before randomizing them otherwise it will not work properly.  For example:

```
function(){
    $(".random_div").show();//make sure all divs are visible
    $("div.randomize").randomize("div.random_div");
    $(".random_div:gt(2)").hide();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will go with kei's solution tho.

Comment: Yes, I agree that his is cleaner and more flexible.